# showing text on page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, html

I am using this code to show a image of a product attribute "brand image"

```
<?php
$brand = $_product->getAttributeText('brand');
$brandImage = str_replace(' ', '_', $brand) . ".jpg";
$brandLink = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $brand)) . ".html";
$brandBaseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl() . '/shop-by-brand/';
?>
<a href="<?php echo $brandBaseUrl . $brandLink; ?>" title="<?php echo $brand; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/media/" . $brandImage); ?>" alt="<?php echo $brand; ?>" />
</a>
```

how could i call text from a html file or a text file named "brand.html or brand.txt brand being which ever brand it is set to like the image it calls above

Comment: Simply use the `fopen()` function, but I would find another way to store this text, as it's not ideal

Comment: sorry coding is not my strong point can you elaborate using the code i provide  not sure what to do with the fopen :)

Comment: would this work im getting a red line flag in dreamweaver   <?php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand'); $file = fopen("/skin/frontend/default/default/images/media/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.txt" alt="'.$brand.'"); ?>

Comment: Remove the alt=".." at the end. This link will help you: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp